# Variable not in scope when using lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I followed the whole tutorial for brick snake game, but I'm facing this error

```
[typecheck -Wdeferred-out-of-scope-variables] [E] • Variable not in scope:
    paused :: Lens.Micro.Type.Getting Bool Game Bool
• Perhaps you meant ‘_paused’ (line 24)
```

The full code is here https://github.com/dhilst/brick-stake-tutorial-exercice-

The important part is this

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, FlexibleContexts #-}

module Snake where

import Control.Applicative ((<|>))
import Control.Monad (guard)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

import Data.Sequence (Seq, ViewL(..), ViewR(..), (<|))
import qualified Data.Sequence as S
import Lens.Micro ((%~), (&), (.~), (^.))
import Lens.Micro.TH (makeLenses)
import Linear.V2 (V2(..), _x, _y)
import System.Random (Random(..), newStdGen)

-- Types
data Game =
  Game
    { _snake :: Snake -- ^ snake as a sequence of points in R2
    , _dir :: Direction -- ^ direction
    , _food :: Coord -- ^ location of the food
    , _foods :: Stream Coord -- ^ infinite list of random food locations
    , _dead :: Bool -- ^ game over flag
    , _paused :: Bool -- ^ paused flag
    , _score :: Int -- ^ score
    , _frozen :: Bool -- ^ freeze to disallow duplicate turns
    }
  deriving (Show)

-- ...

step :: Game -> Game
step g =
  fromMaybe g $ do
    guard (not $ g ^. paused || g ^. dead)
    let g' = g & frozen .~ False
    return . fromMaybe (move g') $ die g' <|> eatFood g'
```

I never used lens before. I tired changing from `paused` to `_paused` since this is the name of the field but it gives me another error

```
[typecheck -Wdeferred-type-errors] [E] • Couldn't match type ‘Bool’
                 with ‘Game -> Data.Functor.Const.Const Bool Game’
  Expected type: Lens.Micro.Type.Getting Bool Game Bool
    Actual type: Game -> Bool
• In the second argument of ‘(^.)’, namely ‘_paused’
  In the first argument of ‘(||)’, namely ‘g ^. _paused’
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘g ^. _paused || g ^. dead’
```

Is there any magic for lens so that you can ommit the `_` that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you generated lenses for the fields? I can't tell, that bit is skipped in your code.

Comment: The tutorial code imports `makeLenses` but doesn't call it! Awkward. If you can find contact information for the tutorial's author, I encourage you to send them a short note.

Answer (score 9):

Haskell doesn't generate lenses by itself. (There was some discussion about whether it should at some point, but I don't think it went very far.)

The `lens` library however has a Template Haskell macro which can do this for you, but you do need to actually *invoke* it!

```
data Game =
  Game
    { _snake :: Snake -- ^ snake as a sequence of points in R2
    , _dir :: Direction -- ^ direction
    ...
    }
  deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Game
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm missing thank you @leftaroundabout I had never used lens before

Comment: @geckos: Be aware that the top-level Template Haskell splice `makeLenses ''Game` is short for the explicit splice syntax `$(makeLenses ''Game)`, and that each top-level splice delimits a *declaration group*, which affects scoping a little. Specifically, the definitions in a module *before* a top-level splice (and including it) may not refer to definitions made *after* the splice, that is, dependencies must be arranged top-to-bottom across splices.